# How to find correct price with recursion?

Tags: php, recursion

First of all Hi and sorry for my English. So my case is to prevent same price for one product. For example I have 3 providers with the same product, but different price

```
product 1 - 12 USD
product 1 - 12.1 USD
product 1 - 55 USD
```

If my price is 55 and I want set 12, program should set 12.2. Cause 12 and 12.1 is already taken. 
Actually I need to find closest, don't taken price with step 0.1

My code does not work:

```
public function findCorrectClosestPrice($price, $products)
    {
        foreach ($products as $product)
        {
            if ($product->price === $price)
            {
                $price = $price + 0.1;
                return $this->findCorrectClosestPrice($price, $products);
            }
            else
            {
                return $price + 0.1;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Can somebody show me where I mistake is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all we need to correct the code. Because of the `if ... else` you will always leave the `foreach` loop, and function, on the first product.

```
public function findCorrectClosestPrice($price, $products)
{
    foreach ($products as $product)
    {
        if ($product->price === $price)
        {
            $price = $price + 0.1;
            return $this->findCorrectClosestPrice($price, $products);
        }
    }
    return $price + 0.1;
}
```

But you're also dealing with floating numbers and you're using the `===` identical comparison operator. That is probably not going to work. Simply put:

```
0.1 + 0.1 === 0.2
```

might return false because the two sides are not exactly the same float value.

The solution is not difficult, just tolerate a slight difference. You can do that this way:

```
public function findCorrectClosestPrice($price, $products)
{
    foreach ($products as $product)
    {
        if (abs($product->price - $price) < 0.0001)
        {
            $price = $price + 0.1;
            return $this->findCorrectClosestPrice($price, $products);
        }
    }
    return $price + 0.1;
}
```

There are other ways of doing this, but they all basically avoid the minor differences that might occur in the float values.

Comment: Thank you! One thing I change its using round() function in my comparison. 
if(round($product->price,1) == round($price,1))

Comment: Yes, `round()` might work as well, but remember that with that you're still directly comparing two floating numbers against each other. That will probably work, but is quite dangerous. You could multiply by ten and then turn the number into an integer with [intval()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php). That is a safe way to compare numbers without using a threshold.